# JavaScript Dates: How do I compare the current date/time against a recurring event?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Let's say I have a list of recurring events that happen the same day and time of the week, e.g. Wednesday 5:30 - 7:30pm.  Obviously I don't want to store a huge number of date strings looking to the future.  What is the best way to store this data so I can test against it with the current date/time.

I'd like to filter a list of events stored as JSON based on if the event is occurring today.  To take it a step further I'd like to test if the event has yet to begin, is currently ongoing, or is complete.

Here's an example of the kind of data I'm working with:

```
"schedule": [
  "wednesday": {
    "open": "5:30",
    "close": "7:30"
  },
  "thursday": {
    "open": "5:30",
    "close": "7:30"
  },
  "friday": {
    "open": "5:30",
    "close": "7:30"
  },
  "saturday": {
    "open": "3:30",
    "close": "4:30"
  },
  "sunday": {
    "open": "2:30",
    "close": "4:30"
  }
]
```

I understand that `Date.getDay();` returns an integer representation of the day-of-the-week so perhaps I should be using that rather than a string representation.

The current schema would require grabbing the hour and minutes from both a `new Date` object, and the daily schedule and comparing them together.  There has to be a better way.

Comment: Use 24-hour times: 17:30–19:30. This way, you can represent any time unambiguously without using [AP]M, and you can parse the time string as valid ISO 8601

Comment: @Roy check out my answer it is what you are looking for...test it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for test it out just change the close time to less than your current time and watch it output closed instead of open:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  "sunday";
weekday[1] = "monday";
weekday[2] = "tuesday";
weekday[3] = "wednesday";
weekday[4] = "thursday";
weekday[5] = "friday";
weekday[6] = "saturday";

var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
var schedule = {
    "wednesday": {
        "open": "5:30 AM",
        "close": "7:30 PM"
    },
    "thursday": {
        "open": "5:30 AM",
        "close": "7:30 PM"
    },
    "friday": {
        "open": "5:30 AM",
        "close": "7:30 PM"
    },
    "saturday": {
        "open": "3:30 AM",
        "close": "4:30 PM"
    },
    "sunday": {
        "open": "2:30 AM",
        "close": "4:30 PM"
    }
};
var dateString = "" + d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate();
var openDate = new Date(Date.parse((dateString + " " + schedule[n].open)));
var closeDate = new Date(Date.parse((dateString + " " + schedule[n].close)));
if((d >= openDate) && (d <= closeDate))
{
    window.alert("Open");
}
else
{
    window.alert("Closed");
}
</script>
```

This will create 3 date objects 1. current date and time (d) 2. open date and time for today (openDate) 3. close date and time for today (closeDate).  It will then compare the current date and time to the other 2 date and times to make sure it falls in that range and output "Open".  If it doesn't fall in the range the it will output "Closed".

UPDATE:

Convert a date to UTC

```
window.alert("" + d.toUTCString());
```

Comment: How does this handle timezones?  Does it default to UTC?

Comment: Storing my dates in local time would mean I'd need to do a conversion if the user is from a different time zone.  Thanks, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you want to use JSON for filtering it looks like you got a pretty ideal format there. You can return the name of the day with:

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
```

It's better to have config files readable rather than easy to program. Use 24 hour time to not have to worry about am/pm business.

Edited per comment:

```
var d = new Date();
var today = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 0,0,0).getTime();
var time = d.getTime() - today; //today's time in miliseconds
```

Comment: Right, so how do I then compare that against the time?  Should I construct a new date object using the current year/month/day and use the `open` time to compare?

Comment: @Roy: See edit. Assuming you want to compare between open and close it'd be easiest to use a 24 hour format. getTime() returns unix time.